# Dealing with bias in multi-channel auto encoders

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, autoencoders, overfitting

### The problem

I have a multi-channel 1D signal I want to auto-encode.
**I am unable to resonstruct the input when the number of channels increases.**

---

### Code

I am using a convolutional encoder, and a convolutional decoder:

`latent_dim: 512`, `frames_per_sample: 128`

```
    self._encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=self._n_in_features, out_channels=50, kernel_size=15, stride=1, padding=7),
        nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=50, out_channels=50, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=3),
        nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=50, out_channels=50, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
        # nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
        nn.Conv1d(in_channels=50, out_channels=1, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0),
        nn.Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1),
        nn.Linear(frames_per_sample, self._config.case.latent_dim)
    )
```

and

```
    start_channels = 256
    start_dim = frames_per_sample // (2 ** 4)

    start_volume = start_dim * start_channels
    self._decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self._config.case.latent_dim, start_volume),
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            # b, latent
            nn.Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(start_channels, start_dim)),
            # b, start_channels, start_dim
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='linear', align_corners=False),
            # b, start_channels, start_dim*2
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=start_channels, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # b, 128, start_dim*2
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            # b, 128, start_dim*2
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='linear', align_corners=False),
            # b, 128, start_dim*4
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=3),
            # b, 64, start_dim*4
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            # b,64, start_dim*4
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='linear', align_corners=False),
            # b, 64, start_dim*8
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=32, kernel_size=11, stride=1, padding=5),
            # b, 32, start_dim*8
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            # b, 32, start_dim*8
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='linear', align_corners=False),
            # b, 32, start_dim*16
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=16, kernel_size=21, stride=1, padding=10),
            # b, 16, start_dim*16
            nn.LeakyReLU(inplace=True),
            # b, 16, start_dim*16
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=self._n_features, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    )
```

I am not putting the entire code/data here because this is a theoretical question, and I don't expect anyone to go and run this.

---

### Results

The result (orange) has artifacts on the edges, relative to the input data (blue):

This is easy to see on training examples:

[image]

Worse - for unseen examples (validation), reconstruction misses on the bias

[image]

---

### Observation

The above only starts to happen when adding more channels, which have different biases.

I am normalizing the entire dataset to sit between -1 and 1, but still each channel has its own typical boundary.

Here is a (nice) result, for a single channel:

[image]

---

### What I think

My guess - Multiple channels force filters to have a single bias, which doesn't fit all of them.
The edges problems are due to bias + zero padding, and the validation data is due to bias that doesn't agree with all channels.

---

### Questions:

1. Does my analysis make sense?
2. What is a possible way to solve this?

---

### My thoughts:

1. A distinct bias *per channel* on at least the last layer. How to do this in Pytorch?
2. Normalizing per-sample (and not per channel) just before passing it to the model, then de normalizing the reconstructed sample.

I don't know how to correctly implement either of those, nor if they make sense, or how to check.

[Also posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090140/dealing-with-bias-in-multi-channel-auto-encoders), but I think this also belongs on ai.stackexchange